# error while uploading a code

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, library, uploading

```
Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

avrdude: can't open input file C:\Users\PETER_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_223764/nyu_probe_activity1_code.ino.hex: No such file or directory
avrdude: read from file 'C:\Users\PETER_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_223764/nyu_probe_activity1_code.ino.hex' failed
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
Invalid library found in D:\programs\ArDuInO\arduino-1.8.5\libraries\OLED_Mono_I2C: D:\programs\ArDuInO\arduino-1.8.5\libraries\OLED_Mono_I2C
Invalid library found in D:\programs\ArDuInO\arduino-1.8.5\libraries\OLED_Mono_I2C: D:\programs\ArDuInO\arduino-1.8.5\libraries\OLED_Mono_I2C

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: `This report would have more information with "Show verbose output during compilation" option enabled in File -> Preferences.` - have you tried?

Comment: Have you installed the Arduino IDE from the Windows appstore? If so, install the newest version from the official website instead, since the appstore Version is known to be faulty